# Image archives from old sources

Tags: images, resource-recommendations

For a personal project I am looking for some examples of libraries/archives that would list scanned imagery from old books, heraldics, drawings, etc. Particularly interested in ancient/prehistoric art and/or scientific/mathematical imagery, but any topic could be useful.

One such archive I found [here](http://etc.usf.edu/clipart/galleries/227-ancient-tools), but looking for a few more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The British Library has [released **over a million images**](http://britishlibrary.typepad.co.uk/digital-scholarship/2013/12/a-million-first-steps.html) on Flickr, all (I believe it is all images. [As stated](http://www.bl.uk/aboutus/terms/copyright/index.html), any images labeled  "no known copyright restrictions" have been released with no restrictions so just keep an eye on the copyright notice for each image) CC0 or Public Domain licensed (i.e. you can do what you like with them).

You can find the images here: [**The British Library | Flickr**](https://www.flickr.com/photos/britishlibrary/)

Comment: Another source is [project gutenberg](https://www.gutenberg.org/), as well as [archive.org](https://archive.org/index.php)